# How to update multiple guests on custom calendar from the android app

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Below added sample code for update guest on custom calendar. but I want to update multiple guests from the android app.

```
ContentValues attValues = new ContentValues();
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "RRD Attendees");
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, "sample@gmail.com");
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_NONE);
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_REQUIRED);
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
attValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, attValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch):

> Each HTTP connection that your client makes results in a certain
>   amount of overhead. The Google Calendar API supports batching, to
>   allow your client to put several API calls into a single HTTP request.
>
> **Examples of situations when you might want to use batching:**
>
> You've just started using the API and you have a lot of data to
>   upload. A user made changes to data while your application was offline
>   (disconnected from the Internet), so your application needs to
>   synchronize its local data with the server by sending a lot of updates
>   and deletes.